# Initialize a const member without a copy constructor with a given value?

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, copy-constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to initialize a const field in constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423696/how-to-initialize-a-const-field-in-constructor)

I have this class:

```
class Foo {
private:
    ...
public:
    Foo() : ... {}
    // no other constructors
    ...
};
```

and another one which holds a Foo member by reference:

```
class Bar {
private:
    const Foo& m_foo;
    ...
public:
    Bar(const Foo& foo);
    // no other constructors
};
```

My question is: how do i initialize the Bar::m_foo reference at the constructor?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you just need `Bar(const Foo& foo) : m_foo(foo) { /* ... */ }`? It isn't totally clear what you're asking for here.

Comment: Note when you use a reference member, you're responsible for making sure you don't use it after its lifetime ends.  This setup is particularly tricky because a temporary `Foo` could be passed to a `Bar` constructor with no compiler warnings....

Comment: By the way, unless you've explicitly disabled Foo's copy constructor, by making it private in C++98/03, or deleting it in C++11, it exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the constructor initialization list:

```
Bar(const Foo& foo) : m_foo(foo)
{
}
```

`const` and reference members **must** be initialized in the initialization list, in this case the member is both.

Comment: Does `m_foo( foo )` call the defined constructor or the default-constructor? Or the copy-constructor?

Comment: @David neither, since m_foo is a reference. No new object is constructed, you're just aliasing an existing object.

Comment: @uv_ `m_foo` is not an object. It's a reference. When you write, for example, `Foo x; Foo& y = x;`, `y` isn't a copy, it's an alias for `x`. Only one object exists.

Comment: No, you're assigning the reference. This is exactly the reason C++11 has added uniform initialization... (to clear up these ambiguities).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: sounds convincing... I missed the notion of a reference not actually being constructed.

Answer (score 3):

Use initializing list:

```
Bar(const Foo& foo):m_foo(foo){}
```