# Constructor initialization error

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, initialization

I'm creating a simple card game foundation and now I'm working on the class that creates objects that represent each player. There seems to be a problem with the constructor though: *Constructor for 'Spelare' must explicitly initialize the reference member 'leken'*

```
class Spelare {
public:
    Spelare(Kortbunt& kortlek, bool ar_dator) {leken = kortlek; dator = ar_dator;} //Constructor
    int spela();

private:
    Kortbunt hand; //The cards in the players hand
    Kortbunt& leken; //The cards on the table
    const bool dator; //Is this player a computer?
};
```

Comment: Assignment is not initialisation. You're assigning to `leken`, you're not initialising it, and you do need to initialise it, like the error message says.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize a const field in constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423696/how-to-initialize-a-const-field-in-constructor)

Comment: It's *very* dangerous to have `Kortbunt& leken` as member data, due to *dangling references*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your constructor to:

```
Spelare(Kortbunt& kortlek, bool ar_dator) : leken(kortlek), dator(ar_dator) {}
```

The problem is that a reference cannot be re-assigned once it has been declared and initialised. Your constructor attempts to declare but not initialise the reference, and then assign to it - which fails.

You need to initialise the reference via the constructor's initialisation list. You also need to do the same for `dator`, since it's `const` - but it's just good practice in general.

Answer (score 0):

References and const members must be initialized like this:

```
Spelare(Kortbunt& kortlek, bool ar_dator) : leken(kortlek), dator(ar_dator) {}
```

However, having a reference as a class member burned me a few times, so I advise against it.

Comment: This still won't compile. `dator` cannot be assigned to either.

Comment: Since dator is const, it also needs to be initialized not assigned. `Spelare(Kortbunt& kortlek, bool ar_dator) : leken(kortlek), dator(ar_dator) {}`

Comment: Like this actually Spelare(Kortbunt& kortlek, bool ar_dator) : leken(kortlek), dator(ar_dator){}; but thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Spelare {
public:
    Spelare(Kortbunt& kortlek, bool ar_dator)
        : leken(kortlek), dator(ar_dator)
    {}

    // ...
};
```

So the trick is to initialize `leken` in an initializer list. This has to be done because it is a reference (mind the `&` in its declaration). And a reference declared in a class simply must be initialized this way.

Finally since `dator` is a const and cannot be assigned neither it has to be initialized in the initializer list, too.

Answer (score 0):

Initialization of class members is *not* performed inside the ctor body. When entering the ctor body all member variables have already been initialized, so *assignment* is instead performed.

Initialization of class members is usually performed using an initialization list.

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int a, int b, int c)
        : a{a}, b{b}, c{c} // Initialization list.
    {
        /* ctor body */
    }
    int a;
    int b;
    const int c;

    std::string s{"Test"}; // C++11 also allows non-const in class initialization.
};
```

As a refererence must be *initialized* to point to some data and it can *not* be reassigned to later point to some other data, the following is an error.

```
struct Bar {
    Bar(Foo& f) // Error: uninitialized reference member.
    {
        f_ = f; // If f_ had been initialized this is assignment to where f_ points,
                // not reassignment of what data f_ is a reference to.
    }
    Foo& f_;
};
```

Also `const` members can not be assigned to (naturally), they must be *initialized* to some value.