# How to initialize an `const int` member in a base class when constructing child?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    const int HP = 200;
    A(){
        std::cout << this->HP << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B();
};
```

Constructing a `B` object will construct the `A` potion first.
I expect to reinitialize `HP` so that `B()` can print new `HP`.
Is this feasible for a base class `const` member ?
I need a member shared between base and child but to be constant in one instance of class, any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423696/how-to-initialize-a-const-field-in-constructor

Comment: The only way is through some constructor of A, by design. Const member are usually a bad idea. In most cases, we have the wrong mental model of the const member. If you think a private member "should" be const, try making it non-const and project its value from change from the outside by the interface. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGCxMmGvocE

Answer (score 1):

You can add a constructor to `A` (and if needed also to `B`) that accepts the value for the `const int` member.
Then when you invoke `A` constructor from `B` constructor via the initializer list, you can pass this `const` value to the base.

Code example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    const int HP = 200;
    A() {
        std::cout << this->HP << std::endl;
    }
//----vvvvvv----vvvvvv--
    A(int hp) : HP(hp) {
        std::cout << this->HP << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() {};
//----vvvvvv----vvvvv--
    B(int hp) : A(hp) {}
};


int main()
{
    B b1;
    B b2{ 99 };
}
```

Output:

```
200
99
```

Note: `B` can also be left as is (without an additional constructor), and pass the required const value to the base.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Further, if there are several such variables in Class A, can Class B specify some variables for initialization, while other variables use the values of Class A?

Comment: `B` is invoking `A` constructor in the initializer list (like `: A(hp)`). As long as there's a constructor for `A` that accepts some of the members, you can use it.

Comment: Is there a general approach? In this case, I may need to set many constructors for Class A.

Comment: That depends on the case. I cannot specify any general approach.

Comment: Well, thank you anyway!